# pkl file for customized image data in pylearn2

Tags: python-imaging-library, deep-learning, ubuntu-15.04, pylearn

I'm totally novice in pylearn2 & right now I'm working in [Brats database](http://braintumorsegmentation.org/) in which we work on 3D MRI of brain for tumor segmentation by using Pylearn2 same as explained in pylearn2 tutorial for [CIFAR10 Database](http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/tutorial/) .

My problem is that all the volumetric images in database is in .mha format and in order to use Pylearn2-CNN I must have either .pkl file or the binary files for the image database. "Image" module can't read .mha file.

Can anybody tell me how to work with .mha files in Pylearn2 and how to generate .pkl file for .mha files.

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting your files from .mha to png and then making a .pkl file.